# probability that balls taken from bag with three red and four white balls ...

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

1.Two balls are randomly taken from a bag containing three red balls and four white balls,

After seeing the color, Two balls are return back to bag. then Two balls are randomly taken again and return to bag

Find probability

A.) two red balls come out
 in the first taking-out, and two white balls are taken out in the next taking-out.

B.)) Consists of two red balls
 and two white balls.

C.)   All four balls taken
 out have the same color.

Let Red =R and white=W 
a.) $P((R,R) \cap (W,W))= \frac{3C2 . 4C2}{7C2 . 7C2}= \frac{2}{49}$ 
b.) $(R,R) , (W,W)$ 
     $(W,W) , (R,R)$ 
    $  (R,W),(W,R)$ 
      $(W,R),(R,W)$ 
first two will be same as a $\frac{2}{49}$  
 and
$P((R,W) \cap (R,W))$=$\frac{3C1 . 4C1}{7C2} \frac{3C1 . 4C1}{7C2}$= 
im not sure about this 
c.) two red and two white 
$P(R,R). P(R,R) = \frac{3C2 . 3C2}{7C2. 7C2}$
$P(W,W). P(W,W) = \frac{4C2 . 4C2}{7C2. 7C2}$

im not sure for the c and d part

Comment: Your question needs to clearly state whether after each single ball selection it is returned to the bag before the next ball selection. Your wording does not make this clear and implies the $2$ balls are only returned after both have been selected. Do you mean "Two balls are randomly taken from a bag containing three red balls and four white balls, with each ball being returned before the next selection"?

Comment: It’s two balls randomly taken from a bag and both return and taken 2 balls again. Yes 2 balls return after both select

Comment: Is (R,W) a different event than (W,R)? If events in denominator are unordered, then events in numerator must also be unordered.

Comment: @BruceET thankyou so I don’t have to count for WR,WR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to part (a) is correct.

For part (b), here are two approaches.

**Method 1:**  Order of selection does not matter.

Then there are three possibilities:

1. Two red balls are drawn the first time and two white balls are drawn the second time, with probability $$\frac{\dbinom{3}{2}}{\dbinom{7}{2}} \cdot \frac{\dbinom{4}{2}}{\dbinom{7}{2}}$$
2. Two white balls are drawn the first time and two red balls are drawn the second time, with probability $$\frac{\dbinom{4}{2}}{\dbinom{7}{2}} \cdot \frac{\dbinom{3}{2}}{\dbinom{7}{2}}$$
3. A red ball and a white ball are drawn each time, with probability $$\frac{\dbinom{3}{1}\dbinom{4}{1}}{\dbinom{7}{2}} \cdot \frac{\dbinom{3}{1}\dbinom{4}{1}}{\dbinom{7}{2}}$$

Since these three cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the probability that two balls of each color will be obtained is
$$\Pr(\text{two balls of each color}) = \frac{\dbinom{3}{2}}{\dbinom{7}{2}} \cdot \frac{\dbinom{4}{2}}{\dbinom{7}{2}} + \frac{\dbinom{4}{2}}{\dbinom{7}{2}} \cdot \frac{\dbinom{3}{2}}{\dbinom{7}{2}} + \frac{\dbinom{3}{1}\dbinom{4}{1}}{\dbinom{7}{2}} \cdot \frac{\dbinom{3}{1}\dbinom{4}{1}}{\dbinom{7}{2}} = \frac{20}{49}$$

**Method 2:**  Order of selection does matter.

Then there are six possibilities:

1. (R,R), (W, W), which occurs with probability $$\frac{3}{7} \cdot \frac{2}{6} \cdot \frac{4}{7} \cdot \frac{3}{6}$$
2. (W, W), (R, R), which occurs with probability $$\frac{4}{7} \cdot \frac{3}{6} \cdot \frac{3}{7} \cdot \frac{2}{6}$$
3. (R, W), (R, W), which occurs with probability $$\frac{3}{7} \cdot \frac{4}{6} \cdot \frac{3}{7} \cdot \frac{4}{6}$$
4. (R, W), (W, R), which occurs with probability $$\frac{3}{7} \cdot \frac{4}{6} \cdot \frac{4}{7} \cdot \frac{3}{6}$$
5. (W, R), (R, W), which occurs with probability $$\frac{4}{7} \cdot \frac{3}{6} \cdot \frac{3}{7} \cdot \frac{4}{6}$$
6. (W, R), (W, R), which occurs with probability $$\frac{4}{7} \cdot \frac{3}{6} \cdot \frac{4}{7} \cdot \frac{3}{6}$$

Observe that the first two cases have the same probability of occurring and that the last four cases have the same probability of occurring.  Since the six cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the probability of obtaining two balls of each color is 
$$\Pr(\text{two balls of each color}) = 2 \cdot \frac{3}{7} \cdot \frac{2}{6} \cdot \frac{4}{7} \cdot \frac{3}{6} + 4 \cdot \frac{3}{7} \cdot \frac{4}{6} \cdot \frac{3}{7} \cdot \frac{4}{6} = \frac{20}{49}$$

For part (c), either all four balls are red, which occurs with probability $$\frac{\dbinom{3}{2}}{\dbinom{7}{2}} \cdot \frac{\dbinom{3}{2}}{\dbinom{7}{2}}$$
or all four balls are white, which occurs with probability $$\frac{\dbinom{4}{2}}{\dbinom{7}{2}} \cdot \frac{\dbinom{4}{2}}{\dbinom{7}{2}}$$  Since these cases are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, the probability that all the balls are the same color is 
$$\Pr(\text{all balls are the same color}) = \frac{\dbinom{3}{2}}{\dbinom{7}{2}} \cdot \frac{\dbinom{3}{2}}{\dbinom{7}{2}} + \frac{\dbinom{4}{2}}{\dbinom{7}{2}} \cdot \frac{\dbinom{4}{2}}{\dbinom{7}{2}} = \frac{5}{49}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! In first method , order of selection does not matter in b part, probability of choosing Red ball and white ball same as white and red ball?

Comment: That is correct.  In the second method, selecting a red ball then a white ball has the same probability of selecting a white ball then a red ball.  Note that the factors in the denominators are the same, while those in the numerators have just been permuted.

Comment: im still little bit confuse, so in combination , choosing red and white also imply choosing white and red? because the order doesnt matter? why P(RR,WW) and P(WW,RR) different?

Comment: When you are working with combinations, what matters are what objects are selected.  Selecting white then red results in the same selection as selecting red then white.  Similarly, choosing two reds then two whites results in the same selection as selecting two whites then two reds.  Note that $$\Pr(RR, WW) = \frac{\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{7}{2}} \cdot \frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{7}{2}} = \frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{7}{2}} \cdot \frac{\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{7}{2}} = \Pr(WW, RR)$$

Comment: why $P(RR,WW) $ and  $ P(WW,RR) $different if order doesnt matter? and why not $P(WR, WR)$ count?

Comment: The above calculation shows that $\Pr(RR, WW) = \Pr(WW, RR)$.

Comment: im sorry, what i mean why when you count $Pr$ for mutually exclusive event,  $P(WR, WR)$ not count?

Comment: Note that the four ordered selections $(RW, RW), (RW, WR), (WR, RW), (WR, WR)$ each correspond to selecting one red and one white ball with each selection.  Therefore, the sum of the probabilities of these four ordered selections is equal to the probability of selecting a red ball and a white ball each time when we make unordered selections.

Comment: Observe that the probability of drawing a red ball and a white ball each time is $$\Pr(RW, RW) = \frac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{7}{2}} \cdot \frac{\binom{3}{1}\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{7}{2}}  = \frac{3}{7} \cdot \frac{4}{6} \cdot \frac{3}{7} \cdot \frac{4}{6} + \frac{3}{7} \cdot \frac{4}{6} \cdot \frac{4}{7} \cdot \frac{3}{6} + \frac{4}{7} \cdot \frac{3}{6} \cdot \frac{3}{7} \cdot \frac{4}{6} + \frac{4}{7} \cdot \frac{3}{6} \cdot \frac{4}{7} \cdot \frac{3}{6}$$

Comment: thankyou so much but why for  $P(RR,WW) $ and $P(WW,RR)$  , we have to count it twice in mutually exclusive event?

Comment: We are making two selections.  There are six ordered selections of balls that result in selecting two red and two white balls.  We accounted for four of them when we calculated the probability of selecting a red ball and a white ball each time.  The other two are the events $(RR, WW)$ and $(WW, RR)$, which correspond to the two ways we could two balls of one color in the first draw and two balls of the other color in the second draw.  We must account for both ways to do this, so we must add the probabilities of these two events.

Comment: thankyou so much, so in conclusion, selections of balls using combination will cover all possible order? and choosing white and white , and red and red are different event so we have to account both ways?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Method that uses random variables rather than events.

---

Let $R_1$ denote the number of red balls that are taken at first time and let $R_2$ denote the number of red balls that are taken at second time.

Observe that $R_1,R_2$ are iid random variables that take values in $\{0,1,2\}$.

Then to be found are the following probabilities:

$P(R_1=2\wedge R_2=0)\tag{A}$
$P(R_1+R_2=2)\tag B$
$P(R_1+R_2=0\vee R_1+R_2=4)\tag{C}$

Setting $p_i=P(R_1=i)$ for $i=0,1,2$ and making use of the fact $R_1,R_2$ are iid we can rewrite:

$p_2p_0\tag{A}$
$p_0p_2+p_1p_1+p_2p_0=2p_2p_0+p_1^2\tag B$
$p_0^2+p_2^2\tag{C}$

Now substitute:

- $p_0=\frac47\frac36=\frac27$.
- $p_1=\frac47\frac36+\frac37\frac46=\frac47$.
- $p_2=\frac37\frac26=\frac17$.

(If you don't understand how the $p_i$ are found then let me know)

In order to find:
$P(R_1=2\wedge R_2=0)=\frac2{49}\tag{A}$
$P(R_1+R_2=2)=\frac{20}{49}\tag B$
$P(R_1+R_2=0\vee R_1+R_2=4)=\frac5{49}\tag{C}$

Answer (score 0):

In (b), with ordered arrangements for both numerators and denominators:
Arrangements RR/WW and WW/RR each have probability $72/42^2.$
Four additional arrangements each have probability $12^2/42^2.$

In (c), arrangement RR/RR has probability $1/49$ and arrangement WW/WW has probability
$4/49.$

A simulation in R with a million iterations, counting the number of red balls
in both draws, gives the following estimated probabilities.

```
set.seed(515)
u = c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0);  m = 10^6
nr.r = replicate(m,  sum(c(sample(u, 2),sample(u, 2))))
table(nr.r)/m
nr.r
       0        1        2        3        4 
 0.081424 0.326159 0.408962 0.163044 0.020411
```

Outcomes for 0, 2, and 4 red balls are relevant to parts (b) and (c), giving about two or three-place accuracy.